# How to use Sharepoint Data Services (listdata.svc) in WCF service project in a site with non-english language?

Tags: wcf, listdata.svc

I have a site collection with Persian language. so lists and fields are in Persian.
When i create a console application and add reference to listdata.svc, i can use the DataContext and add items to a sample list.
But when im in wcf service project and use the same codes and configs, it won't work.
inner exception message is:

> Error processing request stream. The property name 'ایجادشده' specified for type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ParnianQueueListItem' is not
>   valid.

'ایجادشده' field is the same "Created" field in SharePoint Lists.
exception message is:

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was unhandled by user code  
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.  
  Source=System.Data.Services.Client  
  StackTrace:  
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()  
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()  
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)  
       at Parnian.NotificationService.Srv.WcfNotifyMainClassService.AddItemToQueueList(QueueItem item, String configKey)  
       at SyncInvokeAddItemToQueueList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )  
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)  
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure it out.
I just disabled Anonymous Authentication in "_vti_bin" folder of a SharePoint site in IIS which by default it's Enabled.
I actually don't know how it could be related!.